# react-native app stopped working on emulator

Tags: react-native

```
react-native run-android

> Configure project :app
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (28.0.2) is  
ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for   
Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.1.  
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.  
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'" from your  
build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has  
a default version of the build tools.

> Task :app:installDebug
10:56:07 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config
10:56:07 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
10:56:07 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Nexus_5X_API_28(AVD) - 9' for app:debug
10:56:07 D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
10:56:07 D/Device: Uploading file onto device 'emulator-5554'
10:56:07 D/ddms: Reading file permission of /media/rahul/OTHER FILES/mob/practice/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk as: rwxrwxrwx
10:56:07 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
10:56:08 V/ddms: execute 'pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
10:56:08 V/ddms: execute: returning
10:56:08 V/ddms: execute: running rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
10:56:09 V/ddms: execute 'rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
10:56:09 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installed on 1 device.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 8s
28 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 27 up-to-date
Running /home/rahul/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Starting the app on emulator-5554 (/home/rahul/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell am start -n com.practice/com.practice.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.practice/.MainActivity }
```

After a successful build the app opens on the emulator for 1 sec., and a white screen appears then closes. Then it says the app stopped working.

I ran my code on the emulator, but it says the app stopped working.

Comment: Look at the logcat output. It should give you a stacktrace

Comment: whats stacktrace?

Comment: Here's some reading:
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat
https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces

Comment: That was helpful thanks :)

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: yes @yanychar, can you please tell how to close this issue?

Comment: the best way is to post your own answer and to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was solved by just changing the buildToolsVersion to "28.0.3", after this i did react-native run-android and it worked :)